# SharedPreferences on first run are not saved when pressing Back Button

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, back, mobilefirst-runtime

I have an Activity that only runs when the application is opened the first time. Every time I open the app again, this Activity won't run(and this is ok). The problem comes when I press the Back Button the first time I open my app. That Activity appears again and I don't want that to happen. How can I prevent this to happen?

This is my SharedPreferences code on my main activity's onCreate(the variable is created outside):

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And this is the onResume method that let my app know if it's running for the first time:

```
`@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
            // Do first run stuff here then set 'firstrun' as false
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StoryActivity.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        }
       }`
```

Comment: Do you clear your data every time before re-testing it? Because, prefs wouldn't have cleared otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `finish()` on your `MainActivity` before launching the `Intent` to direct to the next `Activity`.  You can also declare [noHistory=true](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to prevent the `Activity` from sticking around.

You can also use [PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int)) to completely change your "launcher" Activity once it's been viewed.

Answer (score 0):

Because your activity is finish after starActivity.Use this, check the working code:

    `@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
            // Do first run stuff here then set 'firstrun' as false
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StoryActivity.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
       }`